# iOS ble app unable to advertise on background

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
                // Override point for customization after application launch.
                peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
                if let user = contants.fetchUsers(context: self.persistentContainer.viewContext){
                    self.user_unique_number = user.uniqueNumber!
                }
                return true
}
        
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
                // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
                // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
        
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
                // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
                // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
                peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : user_unique_number,CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [service_uuid]])
                print("entered background")
}
```

**
so what I am doing is
first initialising the peripheral on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions
when a app enters background i am trying to advertise CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey along with service uuid but its not working
but the same works when app is in active state

**

Comment: add proper Description.

Comment: please format your code... makes it easier for others to support ;-) thx

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising)? - "While your app is in the background, the local name isn’t advertised"

Comment: Ya I read , is there any way I can advertise a unique number when app is in background